# useState is not updating within use effect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I implement a private component by redirecting to the login page when it fails to authenticate or request the page without signing in. When the server sends "Successfully Authenticated", I want the user to see the page such that the isAuth state becomes true.

But when I tried to update it, the state is not updating.

```
if (res.data == "Successfully Authenticated") {
          console.log(res.data);
// printing Successfully Authenticated
          setIsAuth(true);
// isAuth remains false 
        }
```

Could you tell me please why?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import Axios from "axios";

const Private = ({ component: Component, anotherComponent }) => {
  var [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);
  var [isAdminAuth, setIsAdminAuth] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuth) {
      const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem("authenticated");
      let json = JSON.parse(loggedInUser);
      Axios({
        method: "POST",
        data: json,
        withCredentials: true,
        url: "http://localhost:4000/users/login",
      }).then((res) => {
        if (res.data == "Successfully Authenticated") {
          console.log(res.data);
          setIsAuth(true);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [isAuth]);

  return isAuth ? (
    isAdminAuth ? (
      anotherComponent
    ) : (
      Component
    )
  ) : (
    <Navigate to={location.pathname.replace("home", "login")} />
  );
};

export default Private;
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you verifying that isAuth remains false?

Comment: I console logged it right after the ``` setIsAuth(true); ```

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous, try to log it in inside `useEffect(() => {console.log(isAuth)}, [isAuth])`

Comment: You can add a `.finally ` after the `.then()` lime this: `.finally(() => setIsAuth(true));`

Comment: The value of `isAuth` is unchanged in the current context. Setting state triggers a re-render with the *updated* context where `isAuth` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this HOC that i generally use:

```
**
 *
 * PrivateRoutes
 *
 */
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// Utils

const PrivateRoutes = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {  
  var session_token=localStorage.getItem('token')

  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
     session_token !== null ? (
      < Component  {...props} />
      ) : (
            <Redirect to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: props.location }
              }}
            />
          )
      )} 
    />
  )
};


export default PrivateRoutes;
```

Usage:

```
<PrivateRoutes exact path="/companies" name="Companies" component={props => <DefaultLayout {...props}/>} />
```

Comment: In your case you are trying to call API on all the page that contains Private as wrapper. That will call login API multiple times making multiple sessions.